# Problem plotting mean and sd on my graph in R

Tags: r

Could you help me solve my chart problem below.

As you can see it's graphing it, but I'm having problems with the Y axis, it's not showing the mean+standard deviation and mean-standard deviation lines. I think it must be in the ylim setup.

Another thing is that `integer(0)` is showing, what does it mean?

The link to download the database is:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1W_hzuRq7D6X12BdwaXeM-cjg2A5MIKDx/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=102073768617937039119&rtpof=true&sd=true

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)

df<-read_excel('C:/Users/Downloads/database_test1.xlsx')


#calculation of mean and standard deviation

df<-subset(df,df$date2<df$date1) 

dim_data<-dim(df)

day<-c(seq.Date(from = as.Date(df$date2[1]),
                to = as.Date(df$date2[dim_data[1]]),
                by = "1 day"))

df_grouped<-matrix(nrow = 9,ncol=6)
colnames(df_grouped)<-c("Id","date1","date2","Week","D","D1")

df_grouped <- df %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("date"), as.Date)) %>% 
  group_by(date2) %>% 
  summarise(Id = first(Id),
            date1 = first(date1),
            Week = first(Week),
            D = first(D),
            D1 = sum(D1)) %>% 
  select(Id,date1,date2,Week,D,D1)

df_grouped <- df_grouped %>% mutate(date1=format(date1,"%d/%m/%Y"),
                                    date2=format(date2,"%d/%m/%Y"))
df_grouped<-data.frame(df_grouped)

DS=c("Thursday","Friday","Saturday") 

i<-1
df_OC<-subset(df_grouped,is.na(D)) 
ds_OC<-subset(df_OC,df_OC$Week==DS[i])

mean_Week<-mean(as.numeric(ds_OC[,"D1"]) )

sdeviation_Week<-sd(as.numeric(ds_OC[,"D1"]))

#create scatter plot
scatter_date <- function(dt, dta = df) {
  dta %>%
    filter(date2 == ymd(dt)) %>%
    summarize(across(starts_with("DR"), sum)) %>%
    pivot_longer(everything(), names_pattern = "DR(.+)", values_to = "val") %>%
    mutate(name = as.numeric(name)) %>%
    plot(xlab = "Days", ylab = "Types", xlim = c(0, 7),
         ylim = c((min(.$val) %/% 10) * 10, (max(.$val) %/% 10 + 1) * 10))+
    abline(h=mean_Week, col='blue') +
    abline(h=(mean_Week + sdeviation_Week), col='green',lty=2) +
    abline(h=(mean_Week - sdeviation_Week), col='orange',lty=2)
}  

scatter_date("2021-04-10",df)
   > integer(0)
```

[image]

Comment: Take a look again at the *minimal* part of [mcve]. Most of your code here is about filtering data and changing data types. Try to edit that stuff down to just focus on what's relevant to the plot. It would also be better to just post a sample (representative and, again, minimal) of data in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `sdeviation_Week` that you are calculating returns `NA_real_`. Therefore the other two `abline`s beside your `mean` can't be plotted.

The `+` between your `plot` and `abline` causes the return of `integer(0)` which is an empty vector of type `integer`.

So, taking a look at your code, a few suggestions:

0. You didn't define every package used. One was missing:

```r
library(readxl)
```

1. Your definition of `day` is a little bit cumbersome.

```r
day <- c(seq.Date(from = as.Date(head(df$date2, 1)),
                to = as.Date(tail(df$date2, 1)),
                by = "1 day"))
```

returns the same, but you don't need a further definition of `dim_data`.

2. Your first assignment to `df_grouped` is unnecessary. Since you assign it again. Remove those lines:

```r
# df_grouped <- matrix(nrow = 9,ncol=6)
# colnames(df_grouped)<-c("Id","date1","date2","Week","D","D1")
```

3. You are calculating `sdeviation_Week` with a dataset of length 1. For a standard deviation you need at least 2 datapoints. Thus

```r
sdeviation_Week<-sd(as.numeric(ds_OC[,"D1"]))
```

returns `NA` for

```r
> ds_OC
# A tibble: 1 x 6
     Id date1      date2      Week     D        D1
  <dbl> <chr>      <chr>      <chr>    <chr> <dbl>
1     1 20/07/2021 04/03/2021 Thursday NA       18
```

4. Remove the `+` from your scatterplot function:

```r
    plot(xlab = "Days", ylab = "Types", xlim = c(0, 7),
         ylim = c((min(.$val) %/% 10) * 10, (max(.$val) %/% 10 + 1) * 10))
    abline(h=mean_Week, col='blue') 
    abline(h=(mean_Week + sdeviation_Week), col='green',lty=2) 
    abline(h=(mean_Week - sdeviation_Week), col='orange',lty=2)
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Martin, if you can take a look, I think you can help me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68946097/optimize-code-for-scatter-plot-generation-in-r   Thank you so much!

Comment: I proposed an answer.